# Error when using SoapClient but not when using the web browser

Tags: php, web-services, soap

Using the Chronopost Web Services.

When using this post HTTP request in a web browser (account number and password are hidden there, so you can't test yourself unless you have a Chronopost ID) :

```
https://ws.chronopost.fr/shipping-cxf/ShippingServiceWS/shippingWithReservationAndESDWithRefClientPC?subAccount=000&accountNumber=ACCOUNT_NUMBER&password=PASSWORD&shipperCivility=E&shipperName=DELBET&shipperName2=RICHARD&shipperAdress1=1%20rue%20des%20accents&shipperZipCode=28500&shipperCity=Ste%20Gemme%20Moronval&shipperCountry=FR&shipperCountryName=France&shipperContactName=Richard%20Delbet&shipperEmail=richard.delbet@telintrans.fr&shipperPhone=0123456789&shipperMobilePhone=0601020304&recipientCivility=E&recipientName=MALKA&recipientName2=DAVID&recipientAdress1=1%20rue%20des%20essais&recipientZipCode=75001&recipientCity=Paris&recipientCountry=FR&recipientCountryName=France&recipientContactName=David%20Malka&recipientEmail=david.malka@telintrans.fr&recipientPhone=0222426789&recipientMobilePhone=0622220304&shipperRef=CMD1&recipientRef=ART1&productCode=01&shipDate=27/07/2010%2010:00:00&shipHour=10&weight=2&service=0&objectType=MAR&modeRetour=1&mode=PDF
```

I have a valid response with all the correct datas.

When using SoapClient with exactly the same parameters :

```
$client = new \SoapClient("http://ws.chronopost.fr/shipping-cxf/ShippingServiceWS?wsdl");
    $data = [
      'subAccount' => '000',
      'accountNumber' => ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
      'password' => PASSWORD,
      'shipperCivility' => 'E',
      'shipperName' => 'DELBET',
      'shipperName2' => 'RICHARD',
      'shipperAdress1' => '1%20rue%20des%20accents',
      'shipperZipCode' => '28500',
      'shipperCity' => 'Ste%20Gemme%20Moronval',
      'shipperCountry' => 'FR',
      'shipperCountryName' => 'France',
      'shipperContactName' => 'Richard%20Delbet',
      'shipperEmail' => 'richard.delbet@telintrans.fr',
      'shipperPhone' => '0123456789',
      'shipperMobilePhone' => '0601020304',
      'recipientCivility' => 'E',
      'recipientName' => 'MALKA',
      'recipientName2' => 'DAVID',
      'recipientAdress1' => '1%20rue%20des%20essais',
      'recipientZipCode' => '75001',
      'recipientCity' => 'Paris',
      'recipientCountry' => 'FR',
      'recipientCountryName' => 'France',
      'recipientContactName' => 'David%20Malka',
      'recipientEmail' => 'david.malka@telintrans.fr',
      'recipientPhone' => '0222426789',
      'recipientMobilePhone' => '0622220304',
      'shipperRef' => 'CMD1',
      'recipientRef' => 'ART1',
      'productCode' => '01',
      'shipDate' => '27/07/2010%2010:00:00',
      'shipHour' => '10',
      'weight' => '2',
      'service' => '0',
      'objectType' => 'MAR',
      'modeRetour' => '1',
      'mode' => 'PDF',
    ];
    $response = $client->__soapCall("shippingWithReservationAndESDWithRefClientPC", array($data));
```

I have an error returned :

> object(stdClass)#531 (1) {   ["return"]=>   object(stdClass)#537 (2) {
>       ["errorCode"]=>
>       int(1)
>       ["errorMessage"]=>
>       string(3112) " fr.chronopost.soap.shipping.exception.ValidateException    at
>   fr.chronopost.soap.shipping.util.PopulateUtils.populateSkybill(PopulateUtils.java:355)
>     at
>   fr.chronopost.soap.shipping.cxf.ShippingServiceWS.shippingWithReservationAndESDWithRefClientPC(ShippingServiceWS.java:615)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1258.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:285)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.doPost(AbstractCXFServlet.java:153)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
>     at
>   org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
>     at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
>     at
>   org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
>     at
>   org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) "   } }

Unfortunately, the error code "1" is described in the documentation as "system error".

One proabably can't help me directly about the Chronopost Web Services, but maybe I'm missing something into the PHP SoapClient object.

Why do I have a correct response when using a web browser and some kind of ValidateException error when using SoapClient ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When making a SOAP call, you don't need to include URL encoded data strings.  Php soapclient encodes the data into XML automatically.  So the problem is most likely the validation the service is performing on your data, and it's choking on the % characters.  Try changing

```
'shipDate' => '27/07/2010%2010:00:00'
```

to

```
'shipDate' => '27/07/2010 10:00:00'
```